# Reemplazo de -webkit-appearance

Tags: html, css, checkbox

necesitaba usar esta propiedad y su funcion, pero visual studio code no me lo toma por ser obsoleto, alguno tiene idea de como reemplazar esta funcion? Necesito 'invisibilizar' un checkbox

```
input [type="checkbox"]{
-webkit-appearance:none;
position:relative;
width:100%;
cursor:pointer;}
```

Comment: Simplemente `appearance`

Comment: Hola @Yussef ,no funciono

Comment: Ojo que tu selector tiene un error: Esto `input [type="checkbox"]` es distinto a `input[type="checkbox"]` (notar que en el último caso NO hay un espacio entre `input` y `[type="checkbox"]`). El primer selector con espacio (como lo tienes tu) selecciona los elementos hijos de un input que sean del tipo `checkbox` (que no es posible, porque un `input` no tiene elementos hijos). En cambio, sin espacio, selecciona los `input` del tipo `checkbox`

Comment: Ah, que interesante! Me funciono! Muchas gracias @Yussef !!!